# Where does k8s master server resides?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a kubectl installed on the my local system. I connect to K8S running on GCP. Where does my k8s master server run ? On my local machine or on GCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs on GCP in a bunch of VMs managed by Google. Kubectl is a client tool using which you connect to the cluster from your local system. Kubectl uses a config file which has the address of the remote kubernetes master.

Answer (score 1):

In GCP. If you mean GKE specifically, it is running on special magic internal GKE systems you can't see directly.